# Wishlist shows only one item

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, wishlist

I'm looking now for a while but I can not find any solution. 
The Magento wishlist allways replacing the existing wishlist item with the newly added item.

```
SELECT * FROM wishlist_item WHERE wishlist_id LIKE 4578
```

shows allways only one Item.

the part in which the addurl is generated:

```
app\design\frontend\[mytheme]\default\template\catalog\product\view\addto.phtml
```

```
<?php 
    $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
    $_wishlistSubmitUrl = $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product); 
?>
<ul class="wishlist-recommend-links">
    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $_wishlistSubmitUrl ?>" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submitLight(this, this.href); return false;" class="add-to-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>" class="recommend fancybox" data-type="iframe" data-fancybox-width="480" data-fancybox-height="90%"><?php echo $this->__('Recommend product') ?></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the part in which the wish list will be displayed:

```
\app\design\frontend\[mytheme]\default\template\wishlist\item\list.phtml
```

```
<?php
    $columns = $this->getColumns();
?>
<table class="data-table cart-table" id="wishlist-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                <th><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if (count($this->getItems())): ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $item): ?>
                <tr id="item_<?php echo $item->getId();?>">
                    <?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
                        <td><?php $column->setItem($item); echo $column->toHtml($item);?></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php else: ?>
                <td colspan="<?php echo count($columns);?>" class="wishlist-empty"><?php echo $this->__('This Wishlist has no Items');?></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <?php echo $column->getAdditionalHtml();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    decorateTable('wishlist-table');

<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <?php echo $column->getJs();?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
//]]>
</script>
```

Does anyone have the same problem and possibly a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override core classes **Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection** and **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection** according to diff:

**Mage_Wishlist_Model_Resource_Item_Collection**

```
@@ -184,9 +184,13 @@
         $this->_productIds = array_merge($this->_productIds, array_keys($productIds));
         $attributes = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/config')->getProductAttributes();
-        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
+
+        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $productCollection */
+        $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
+            ->setUseLeftJoinForPriceIndex(true);
+
         foreach ($storeIds as $id) {
-            $productCollection->addStoreFilter($id);
+            $productCollection->addWebsiteFilter(Mage::app()->getStore($id)->getWebsiteId());
         }

         if ($this->_productVisible) {
```

And **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection**:

```
@@ -132,13 +132,20 @@
     protected $_productCountSelect           = null;

     /**
-     * Enter description here ...
+     * Is website filter
      *
      * @var bool
      */
     protected $_isWebsiteFilter              = false;

     /**
+     * Type of joining price index table
+     *
+     * @var bool
+     */
+    protected $_useLeftJoinForPriceIndex     = false;
+
+    /**
      * Additional field filters, applied in _productLimitationJoinPrice()
      *
      * @var array
@@ -1759,11 +1766,15 @@
     /**
      * Join Product Price Table with left-join possibility
      *
+     * @param bool|null $joinLeft
+     *
      * @see Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::_productLimitationJoinPrice()
      * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
      */
-    protected function _productLimitationPrice($joinLeft = false)
+    protected function _productLimitationPrice($joinLeft = null)
     {
+        $joinLeft = is_null($joinLeft) ? $this->_useLeftJoinForPriceIndex : $joinLeft;
+
         $filters = $this->_productLimitationFilters;
         if (empty($filters['use_price_index'])) {
             return $this;
@@ -2172,4 +2183,18 @@

         return $this->_pricesCount;
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Set type of joining price index table
+     *
+     * @param bool $value
+     *
+     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
+     */
+    public function setUseLeftJoinForPriceIndex($value)
+    {
+        $this->_useLeftJoinForPriceIndex = (bool)$value;
+
+        return $this;
+    }
 }
```

Comment: btw. You can also say why this is necessary?

Comment: Yes, because in query was used inner join for joining price index, and in case when price data are absent in index, your product will skipped.